# Unit Testing Angular service with nested promises with $http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

I am, using jasmine, trying to test the following function as a part of an angular service

```
service.initialize = function (params) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $q.all([service.getSpecs(params), service.getValData(params), service.getRelatedMeasures(params)])
        .then(function (values) {
            $q.all([service.getIssues(), service.getData(params, values)])
                .then(function (values) {
                    defer.resolve(values);
                });
        });
    return defer;
};
```

Each of the referenced functions in both of the `$q.all()` statements contains an `$http` call.

In my test, I am mocking all of the `$http` calls using `$httpBackend`.  My test looks something like this:

```
describe('the intialize function', function () {
    var mockParams = {};
    beforeEach(function () {
        svc.initialize(mockParams);
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
    it('should call the getSpecs function', function () {
        expect(editorSvc.getSpecs).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockParams);
    });
});
```

However, I get an error that there are still `$http` requests in the queue.  I have tried calling `$httpBackend.flush()` again, and also including `$rootScope.$apply()` in various orders and I can't get it to resolve the inner promise.

Any way around this?

Comment: Do you have any code in your tests that uses `$httpBackend.expectGET()` or `$httpBackened.whenGET()`?

Comment: I have each of the `$http` calls configured in my initial `beforeEach` as such: `$httpBackend.when('GET', '../api/DataEdit/GetIssues').respond(200, expectedIssues);` and it works fine if I'm testing just one series of `$http` calls